# Add elements to canvas html5

Tags: html, canvas

It is possible to add elements inside HTML5's canvas?

For example:

```
<canvas id="canvas2" width="650" height="850"> 
    <div class="draggable" class="ui-widget-content" width='100px' height='100px'>
       <textarea class="resizable" rows="2" cols="10" style="color: #FF0707; ">
        Example
       </textarea>
    </div>
</canvas>
```

That doesn't show anything... however, if I put that draggable div inside any other element in the html it works...

What am I missing?

Thx.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You cannot add elements into the canvas like that.
The `innerHTML` of the canvas is shown when a browser does not suport `<canvas>`.
You should extra elements beside the canvas, or a `<div>` layer above the canvas.

```
<canvas id="canvas2" width="650" height="850"> 

</canvas>
<div style="position: absolute; top: 50px; left: 50px; width: 100px; height: 100px; z-index: 5;" class="draggable" class="ui-widget-content">
   <textarea class="resizable" rows="2" cols="10" style="color: #FF0707; ">
      Example
   </textarea>
</div>
```

See also: 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Canvas_tutorial/Basic_usage#Fallback_content

Answer (score 1):

Canvas elements are replaced elements. They render a bitmap. Their content, like that of `<iframe>`s and `<object>`s is for use when the element is not supported.

What you are trying to do is akin to putting elements inside an image.

> The contents of the canvas element, if any, are the element's fallback content.

— http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/the-canvas-element.html#the-canvas-element